# VPN на резервном канале. Cisco ASA 5505

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

Есть Cisco ASA 5505, версия 8.2(5), на ней настроен два внешних интерфейса - "основной" outside и "резервный" backup. В случае, если основной канал падает, переключаемся на резерв, тут все хорошо и работает).
И есть VPN между outside и удаленным хостом. Проблема в том, что в случае переключения на резерв, VPN, конечно же, отваливает.
ASA (через ASDM) не дает добавлять VPN, если есть другой с таким же ip назначения.Вот и вопрос - как можно эту ситуацию разрулить?
Спасибо!

***Небольшой UPD, 05.07.2012***
Cейчас на главной cisco:

```
  crypto map vpdn 1 match address outside_1_cryptomap
  crypto map vpdn 1 set pfs group1
  crypto map vpdn 1 set peer aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
  crypto map vpdn 1 set transform-set ESP-DES-SHA
  crypto map vpdn 2 match address outside_2_cryptomap
  crypto map vpdn 2 set pfs group1
  crypto map vpdn 2 set peer bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb
  crypto map vpdn 2 set transform-set ESP-DES-SHA
  crypto map vpdn 3 match address outside_3_cryptomap
  crypto map vpdn 3 set pfs group1
  crypto map vpdn 3 set peer ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc
  crypto map vpdn 3 set transform-set ESP-DES-SHA
  crypto map vpdn 10 ipsec-isakmp dynamic vpdn-map
  crypto map vpdn interface outside
  crypto map vpdn interface backup

  access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 dop-off1 255.255.255.0
  access-list outside_2_cryptomap extended permit ip 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 dop-off2 255.255.255.0
  access-list outside_3_cryptomap extended permit ip 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 dop-off3 255.255.255.0
```

На одной из удаленных cisco, на которой тестируюсь:

```
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_1_cryptomap  
crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs group1  
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer (ip outside-интерфейса "главной" cisco)  
crypto map outside_map 1 set transform-set ESP-DES-SHA  
crypto map outside_map 2 match address outside_1_cryptomap  
crypto map outside_map 2 set pfs group1  
crypto map outside_map 2 set peer (ip backup-интерфейса "главной" cisco)  
crypto map outside_map 2 set transform-set ESP-DES-SHA  
crypto map outside_map interface outside  

access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip object-group INSIDE_HOSTS object-group REMOTE_HOSTS
```

Вывод результатов packet-tracer:

```
...      
Phase: 11      
Type: VPN      
Subtype: encrypt      
Result: DROP      
Config:      
Additional Information:       
Forward Flow based lookup yields rule:       
out id=0xd8e3d950, priority=70, domain=encrypt, deny=false              
hits=0, user_data=0x0, cs_id=0xd8e99c80, reverse, flags=0x0, protocol=0              
src ip=192.168.10.0, mask=255.255.255.0, port=0              
dst ip=dop-off1, mask=255.255.255.0, port=0, dscp=0x0            
Result:      
input-interface: inside      
input-status: up      
input-line-status: up      
output-interface: inside      
output-status: up      
output-line-status: up      
Action: drop      
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
```

Если основной канал поднят, то sh isakmp выводит:

```
Active SA: 3          
Rekey SA: 0 (A tunnel will report 1 Active and 1 Rekey SA during rekey)      
Total IKE SA: 3            
1   IKE Peer: ***.***.***.***          
Type    : L2L             
Role    : initiator          
Rekey   : no              
State   : MM_ACTIVE      
2   IKE Peer: ***.***.***.***          
Type    : L2L             
Role    : initiator          
Rekey   : no              
State   : MM_ACTIVE      
3   IKE Peer: ***.***.***.***          
Type    : L2L             
Role    : responder          
Rekey   : no              
State   : MM_ACTIVE
```

А если основной интерфейс отключен, то выводит, что нет ни одного туннеля...    Вот что с этим делать? :)

Comment: Перезапуск VPN  не помогает?

Comment: А никак, ip адреса на интерфейсах то разные. Вам надо на удаленном хосте править ip адрес пира?!

Comment: @Dex - Дело не в перезапуске. ASDM ругается, при попытке создать VPN, на то, что нельзя делать два канала с одинаковым ip назначения.  @pyatak - на удаленном хосте добавили vpn с другим ip назначения (ip нашего резерва), только вот надо еще и на нашей стороне добавить такой канал, а не дает.

Comment: в интернетах пишут, что это можно разрулить маршрутизацией и треками, только вот в толк не возьму, каким образом...

Comment: Так я понимаю, что с маршрутизацией Вы уже разобрались. Полагаю, с помощью метрик?!

Comment: Переключение каналов организовано так:  route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх 1 track 1  route backup 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 ууу.ууу.ууу.ууу 10  !  sla monitor 1   type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх interface outside   num-packets 3   frequency 10  sla monitor schedule 1 life forever start-time now  !  track 1 rtr 1 reachability

Comment: Просто я к чему, канал ipsec не привязывается в интерфейсу, он описывается access-list ом, только вот я не в курсе как это реализовано у вас,через ASDM, но через консоль добавив access-list с нужным ip адресом, вы решите свою проблему.

Comment: В интернетах набрел на совет добавитьcrypto map <my_map> interface backupПопробовал, отправив основной канал в shutdown - не поперло. Packet-tracer шаге на 11-ом показал DROP сославшись на acl, но вроде в acl'ях привязанных к крипто-мапам все ровно. В общем, на следующей неделе (если за выходные не настрою нормально GNS3 на домашней машине), буду тестировать. Отпишусь о результатах.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо привести конфигурацию удаленной Cisco к следующему виду:

```
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_1_cryptomap  
crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs group1  
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy  
crypto map outside_map 1 set transform-set ESP-DES-SHA
```

где xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx и yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - ip-адреса основного и резервного интерфейсов "главной" Cisco.
Также необходимо создать tunnel-group для резервного ip:

```
tunnel-group xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx type ipsec-l2l  
tunnel-group xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ipsec-attributes  
 pre-shared-key *****  
tunnel-group yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy type ipsec-l2l  
tunnel-group yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy ipsec-attributes  
 pre-shared-key *****
```

Если на обеих точках есть резервные каналы и необходимо переключение, аналогичные настройки делаются на обеих Cisco.
В ASDM все делается предельно просто:
добавляем пиров
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

добавляем tunnel-group
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не забываем про NAT и access-list'ы.